# Как обработать событие нажатия по кнопкам input type='number'?

Tags: javascript, события, input

Как обработать событие нажатия по кнопкам `input type='number'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно отслеживать именно нажатие и/или удержание контролов, то необходимо добавить пару строк, чтобы событие `oninput` не срабатывало при изменении значения другими способами (например, колесом мыши или вводом с клавиатуры):

```js
var oInputNumber = document.querySelector('input[type="number"]');

oInputNumber.addEventListener('mousedown', function() { this.which = true; });
oInputNumber.addEventListener('mouseup', function() { this.which = false; });
oInputNumber.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (this.which) { console.log('value change to:', this.value); }
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=\"number\"]").addEventListener("input", function() {
  console.log("value change");
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = document.getElementById('input_Id');
addEventListener('click', hundelBottom);
 function hundelBottom(event) {
     console.log(event.target.value)
}
```